# Force iOS UIWebView to 1024px, not 1027px

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView shown in an iPad screen (iOS7, landscape). The web page is exactly 1024 x 768.

If I inspect the view at runtime (using revealapp.com) I can see the width of the UIWebView is 1024px. However, it contains a UIWebBrowserView within it, which is showing as 1027px wide.

[image]

The upshot of this is that the user can scroll the web page 3px horizontally, which is annoying. It should fit perfectly and be "locked" when the page loads. I still allow pinch zooming using these settings.

```
self.webView.delegate = self;
self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

If I inspect the DOM of the webpage running in the app using Safari, I can see that the web page itself is definitely 1024px wide. So, it seems iOS is causing the problem.

**So... does anyone know how I can force the UIWebBrowserView to 1024px rather than 1027px?**

Thanks

Tobin

Comment: have you thought of doing either the initializer, or setting the frame?

Comment: i´d set the UIWebBrowserView´s frame to the desired size when you initialize the item. Something like this: `UIWebBrowserView *browser = [[UIWebBrowserView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];`. Have you done that yet? if self.view.frame.size.width doesn´t work, just try **512** instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you could try here:

1. Zoom in the content using the `scrollView` property of your UIWebView by setting it's `contentSize` to your desired size (you may need to play with the `contentOffset`, too, until you get it right).
2. Set an appropriate `viewport` meta tag on your web page to control the layout on a mobile device. Something along these lines:

   `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Hope this helps.